# C# WebAPI redirect to a Link that displays an Image

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, http-redirect

```
    public HttpResponseMessage getLogoPath(int ID)
    {
        String urlsubfix = dataManager.getMobileLogoPath(ID);
        String urlToReturn =  PictureController.urlprefix  +urlsubfix;
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(urlToReturn);
        return response;
    }
```

I want to have one of the API call to return an image, how I am accomplishing that is to redirect to another link that has the image,  for example :

http://steve.files.wordpress.com/2006/03/Matrix%20tut%202.jpg

I am trying to use PostMan to test this and it gives me back a broken image. I tried derping around and still couldn't find a solution.

-----Edit part of the code that needs this

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCustomerBarCodeLogo(String ID)
    {
        Barcode BC = new Barcode();
        Image img =BC.Encode(TYPE.CODE128, "123456789");
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        ImageConverter imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] resourceByteArray = (byte[])imageConverter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
        MemoryStream dataStream = new MemoryStream(resourceByteArray);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
        return result; 
    }
```

[image: Result from postman]

This returns a broken image.

------Newest Update

I sort of found out the problem.  What happens is that there is a problem with SSL basic authentication.  What happens is when the first time the client wants to pass in a request, the authentication was set correctly.  However, when it tries to get an image which is another request after that is triggered by internal code, that request does not have autherizationHeader and it is not authenticated.  I don't know where is the 2nd event triggered so I don't know how to manually set that header.

Comment: The redirect is probably not sending the auth header.  Have you tried your redirect from a regular client with a credential cache set up?

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, because even when I try to load a image from a directory and return it in Bytes it still doesn't display

Comment: But it does work when you go directly against the URL, correct?  It's only when you redirect that the URI is broken?

Comment: I sort of found out the problem.  What happens is that there is a problem withe SSL basic authentication.  What happens is when the firs t time the client wants to pass in a request, the authentication was set correctly.  However, when it tries to get an image which is another request after that is triggered by internal code, that request does not have autherizationHeader and it is not authenticated.  I don't know where is the 2nd event triggered so I don't know how to manually set that header.

Comment: By default the HttpClientHandler which is inside HttpClient will do autoredirects.  If you want to send credentials automatically then you will need to setup all the credentials in the CredentialCache for all the hosts you want to access.  HttpClientHandler will look in the credential cache for the host you are calling and if it finds credentials it will apply them to the redirect request.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot redirect to response an image in this url, your caller would be able to change the location.

First solution, try using directly the image result for web api, for sample:

```
public HttpResponseMessage getLogoPath(int id)
{
    string pathImage = // a way to get the imagem path..

    // create response
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(); 

    // set the content (image)
    response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(pathImage));

    // set the content type for the respective image
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png"); // or jpg, gif..

    return response;
}
```

Or use Moved Status Code, for smaple:

```
public HttpResponseMessage getLogoPath(int ID)
{
    String urlsubfix = dataManager.getMobileLogoPath(ID);
    String urlToReturn =  PictureController.urlprefix + urlsubfix;

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(urlToReturn);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to return the file in "http://steve.files.wordpress.com/2006/03/Matrix%20tut%202.jpg" instead of acturally saving that file in my memory and than returning it?

Comment: "Moved Status Code, for smaple" is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate way that might work for you.  This is the close the the technique I use.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetCustomerBarCodeLogo(String ID)
{
    Barcode BC = new Barcode();
    Image img =BC.Encode(TYPE.CODE128, "123456789");

    var dataStream = new MemoryStream();
    img.Save(dataStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    dataStream.Position = 0;

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
    return result; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FileResult for example

```
public FileResult GetLogo(string imageName)
{
    return File(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images/") + imageName, "image");
}
```

In this case the File function takes the file path and content type and returns a file response.

Comment: this is not exactly waht I want to accomplish, I want to redirect to another Http url that has an image